# Can't append all values to dictionary using for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I want to append some values in a list to a dictionary but its only appending the last one

Code:

```py
l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
a = {}
for i in l:
        a['r'] = [i]
print(a)
```

Ouput:

```py
{'r': [(3,4)]}
```

Ouput i want:

```py
{'r': [(1,2),(3,4)]}
```

Comment: You're replacing the value of `a['r']` rather than appending to it each iteration. You seem like you literally just want `a = { 'r': l }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
a = {}
a['r'] = []
for i in l:
        a['r'].append(i)
print(a)
```

or simply you can do

```
l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
a = {}
a['r'] = l

print(a)
```

this is the output

```
{'r': [(1, 2), (3, 4)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

More general solution using `setdefault`:

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
a = {}
for i in l:
    a.setdefault('r', []).append(i)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
{'r': [(1, 2), (3, 4)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `defaultdict` from the standard library collections module

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(list)

l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
for i in l:
        a['r'].append(i)
print(a)
```